# Is spawning a new thread risky in ASP.Net app

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

In an ASP.Net app, is it ok to spawn a new thread as in code below, or there are some hidden risks?

In this code, I am executing some code that takes a long time to execute like 2 to 5 minutes, on this newly spawned thread. The thread spawned is not a background thread.

I am thinking if there are many users who click the button 'btnLongRequest', then it means there will be many new threads spawned, which may not be a good thing, but not sure.

```
 protected void btnLongRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        LongOps lo = new LongOps();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(lo.LongOp));
        t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        t.Start();
 }
```

Comment: It's going to depend on how many users you expect to hit that button. It's not very scalable to create a thread for each request. If requests really take 5 minutes I would think you need some dedicated background task to handle those and queue them if you're getting an unexpected volume of requests.

Comment: @XavierLeclercq, By queueing you mean use a windows service or it can still be done within the ASP.Net app?

Comment: Yes I would create a separate service for this. Not sure how feasible this since I don't have all the details. But a request that can take 2-5 minutes is very long. What happens when you need to reboot the server or a crash happens? Somehow you'll want the requests to be executed anyway. So you'd need some kind of persistence anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The biggest problem is that background work in ASP.NET can be lost due to a variety of circumstances.](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) Can you tolerate this work to be occasionally lost without notice?

Having many threads becomes a problem if you start to exhaust the thread-pool limits (you are not because you are using your own threads). Or, you are overloading the machine and exhausting some resource like CPU, memory (each thread has 1MB of stack size by default), disk or network.

If you avoid those problems you are fine.

Comment: The OS supports only a limited number of threads, once you go past that you can't create anymore

Comment: @usr, The code I am executing on this thread needs to reliably run. I could put the long op code in a try catch which will prevent any exception from bringing down the AppDomain, but as paulm mentioned there is a limit to how many such threads could be spawned.

Comment: @usr, The only problems I see are if AppPool gets recycled causing the code execution to be suddenly stopped, or if OS does not allow more threads to be created which can happen if a lot of users hit the page for long ops. So there is always a degree of unreliability in my approach of spawning a new thread.

Comment: @paulm the limits are insanely high. In practice, memory is the limiting factor. 10k threads are totally OK for the OS but they consume 10GB of memory.

Comment: @Sunil you cannot control all reasons that abort background work. One of the reasons is an outright bug in your code (for example, a stack overflow instantly kills the process). You can never exclude that possibility. See also my previous comment regarding limits. They are not a practical concern. You will max out some other resource before hitting OS limits.

Comment: Consider using async IO so that you don't need that many threads. Async IO does not use any thread at all while the IO is running.

Comment: I've found that its not possible to create 10k threads in Windows server as it is limited by the paged pool kernel memory which is limited

Comment: @paulm depends on bitness, OS and memory available: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx He was able to create 55,000 threads there. And there does not seem to be any inherent limit. Memory was the limiting factor here. My computer has about 3000 threads running right now.

Comment: "32-bit Testlimit was able to create 3,204 threads on 64-bit Windows" seems to be pretty much what I was seeing

Comment: @usr, I think I need to use some other approach rather than this spawning thread approach, as there are a lot of risks and most important the long ops code  is not guaranteed to execute till completion.

Comment: @usr, Is 'Consider using async IO' approach that you suggested in one of your comments the same as Async Page in ASP.Net ( i.e. Async = 'true' in Page directive)?

Comment: Async IO is a general concept. Basically, all the asynchronous APIs in .NET (e.g. Stream.ReadAsync instead of Stream.Read) issue async IO to the OS. If you use those (in any way you like - the most modern being await) you will not block threads for the duration of the IO.

Comment: @usr, I think for long ops method I could just call a One-Way WCF method, so my page would return quickly and the page would simply say 'Your long ops request is in progress and an email will be sent when it completes'.  The idea is to return the page to browser as quickly as possible and let the long operation execute within a WCF web service.

Comment: True, but now the long-running operation is just somewhere else: On the WCF service. Same problem. I have written an answer about how to approach such things but I can't find it at the moment. Not an easy problem to solve, alas.

Comment: @usr. Ok. Thanks. I hope you find it.